# How to only use mod_rewrite to access PHP files and disable natual way to refer to the PHP file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am very new to these issues, please help.

I have two questions regarding to mod_rewrite (apache 2.2).

1) What I want to do is to for example, rewrite /login to login.php. This can be done by

```
RewriteRule ^/?login/?$ /login.php [L]
```

However, what I wanted to do too is to disable users to access /login.php directly.

If I just write,

```
RewriteRule ^/?.*\.php$ /file_not_exist.html [L]
```

This doesn't work and even /login will be rewritten to /file_not_exist.html.

Is there any way to do that? I notice that in Apache 2.5 documents, there is an [END] flag but I can't use it yet in Apache 2.2.

2) I want to replace all ajax request to /ajax/action, the following will do,

```
RewriteRule ^/?ajax/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /ajax/$1.php [L]
```

However, when I try to access /ajax/xyz where xyz.php doesn't exist, the browser will show that "/ajax/xyz.php" doesn't exist, which will make ppl know that /ajax/action is implemented by /ajax/action.php.

How to disable such /ajax/xyz.php doesn't exist message? The only way I can think of now is to enumerate all files in ajax direction and do the following,

> RewriteRule ^/?ajax/(action1|action2|action3)/?$ /ajax/$1.php [L]

Then when user access /ajax/xyz, it will just say /ajax/xyz doesn't exist but not /ajax/xyz.php. But this is very troublesome. Is there any better way to do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to restrict requests for /login.php, you need to use a RewriteCond to check the actual request. Otherwise you're going to go into a loop.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /login.php
RewriteRule ^ /file_not_exist.html [L]
```

You could also redirect them to `/login` if you want and let the first rule take care of it:

```
RewriteRule ^ /login/ [L,R=301]
```

2) You can check if an actual file exists before you rewrite the php, again by using RewriteCond and checking using "-f"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ajax/(.+)/?
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ajax/%1.php !-f
RewriteRule ^ /ajax/no_action.php [L]
```

So first we check to make sure the request starts with "/ajax/" and we select the next part "(.+)". In the next RewriteCond, we use the %1 backreference to access the previous match. So if the request was for "/ajax/blahblah/", the next RewriteCond would check for "/doc_root/ajax/blahblah.php". The !-f means "if the file doesn't exist". Thus, in this example, if "/doc_root/ajax/blahblah.php" doesn't exist, then we rewrite the request to "/ajax/no_action.php". You'd have to replace that with something that you want to handle all of the "bad" requests. Maybe point it to a blank script that simple does nothing so nobody would know the wiser. You can then make a rewrite to change /ajax/(.+)/ to /ajax/$1.php:

```
RewriteRule ^ajax/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /ajax/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 RewriteRule ^/?.*\.php$ /file_not_exist.html [L]
```

This would work. But not when you make it the second RewriteRule. Order is important. See also [Serverfault: Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

More specifically you could probe the `%{REQUEST_URI}` directly for existence `-f` and then if it matches the `.*\.php($|/)` pattern.

---

I don't quite get your second question. But it seems you should utilize PATH_INFO there:

```
 RewriteRule ^/?ajax/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /ajax.php/$1 [L]
```

Because rewriting to a non-existent `$1.php` must obviously result in an error.

(If this is a real directory with real scripts however, then again just use the `RewriteCond` with `-f` test.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do for my website:
(1) define properly 404 in your vhost, (and this is an answer to your second question: write your own 404 file where you show only what you want. For example check the IP address and if it's local (= dev environment) then show a lot of information)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

(2) Forbid any direct access to php files:

```
RewriteRule (.*)php$ - [L,R=404]
```

Tell me if this works